# How to find in git log the commit indicated in the gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

Please see the image of the environment in gitlab
There is a commit version  8d6995e4 in our case.  I am doing git log | grep and cannot find this commit version.  What this string indicates?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

When you run `git log` you tell it which commit to start with.  If you don't tell it, it assumes the current commit from the current branch.  It finds the rest of the commits that it *can* find from that starting-point.  You have commit `8d6995e4` in your repository, but it's not on your current branch.

You might use `git log --all` to tell it to start from *all* the recorded starting-points (branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on), and you might want to [Get Help From A Dog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452), or as [OznOg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503148/how-to-find-in-git-log-the-commit-indicated-in-the-gitlab#comment95810692_54503182), use a visual viewer.  See also [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).

## Long

To understand what's going on here, you need to understand *commits*—which are Git's [*raison d'être*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raison_d'%C3%AAtre)—and how Git finds them, usually starting from branch names.  This gets into the idea of *reachability* in a graph, which is explained in an even longer and more thorough way at [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

#### Commits

Every commit has its own unique hash ID.  That's that big ugly string you see here, `8d6995e4` (though in fact it's much longer—40 characters of apparently-random junk, and not actually random at all).  That hash ID is the "true name" of the commit: it's how Git finds the commit, in the database of "all commits ever" (to which the main thing people do is add more commits).

Every commit also holds a *parent* commit hash ID.  That is, the child of some parent commit remembers the parent's hash.  Parents do not remember their children because once a commit is made, *nothing inside it can ever change.*  This frozen-ness of commits does not matter for `git log` but does matter for many other Git commands.

The above is a slight exaggeration, because, at least one commit—the very first one someone makes in a new and empty repository—has *no* parent.  The parent of *this* commit is the commit that comes before *this* commit.  The first commit has no commit that comes before it.  And, merge commits have more than one parent, which is what makes them merge commits.

What all this means is that commits form a *backwards-looking chain*.  It's this backwards chain that `git log` uses.   Here's a simple drawing of a repository with just three commits, where instead of big ugly 40-character hash IDs, I use just one uppercase letter.  Obviously we'll run out pretty fast–the repository will be full at 26 commits—so this is not the way Git does it, but it *does* illustrate the issue just fine.  Our very first commit is `A`, which has *no* parent.  Then we make `B` which gets `A` as its parent, and last, we make `C` which gets `B` as its parent.

```
A <-B <-C
```

Because nothing inside a commit can ever change, we can draw the connections that go backwards from child to parent as lines that go both ways, as long as we remember that *Git* has to go backwards.  This is more convenient for me in StackOverflow postings, because I also sometimes need to do diagonals:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

and I have no convenient text arrows that work for everyone here.

#### Branch names point to commits, but also move

Now, for `git log` to work, you *must give it a starting commit*—a hash ID.  In fact, for very many things in Git to work, you have to give them a hash ID.  But real hash IDs are big and ugly (`8d6995e4`) and apparently-random.  They are definitely not in a sensible order, and there is no way for humans to remember them.  So what we do is we pick out a *branch name*, such as `master`.  We have Git shove the hash ID of the *last* commit into the branch name, which means our drawing now looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

The *name* lets Git find the *last* commit, in this case `C`.  From there, `git log` walks *backwards* to `B`, and then back to `A`, and then since `A` has no parent, Git can finally stop.

To add a *new* commit, Git will package up whatever it is you are committing—a new snapshot—and add *metadata* like your name and email address, the current time, and your log message.  Git will automatically add to the metadata the hash ID of the *current* commit.  Git writes all of that into the object database, and the act of writing it assigns this new commit its unique hash ID.  That, of course, is some other big ugly number, but we'll use the letter `D`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D
```

To rememeber that `D` *is* our last commit, Git now updates our name `master`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- master
```

So now `git log` will start at `D`, then show `C`, then `B`, then `A`.

#### Using your HEAD to change what you see and update

It's the *commits* that matter.  The branch names are there to help us find them.  But what happens when we have several branch names?  Let's look at a slightly more complicated graph, after we've made a few more commits:

```
...--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F   <-- develop
```

We said above that when we make a new commit, Git moves the branch name.  But how does Git know *which branch name* to move?  If we had:

```
...--C--D   <-- develop, master
```

—and we probably did at some point—how does Git know, when we make commit `E`, that it's *develop* that should move, and not `master`?

The answer is that we use `git checkout` to attach the special name `HEAD` to just one branch.  If we pick `develop`, we get:

```
...--C--D   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

Then when we add commit `E`, Git moves `develop`:

```
...--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` stays attached to the branch name, even as the branch name itself moves.  (The actual implementation of this, for those who are curious, is that there is a file in `.git` named `HEAD`, that simply contains the branch name itself.  So the contents of `HEAD` only change when you pick a new branch to use.  The contents of the *branch name*—the hash IDs for the latest commit for `master` and `develop`—are stored elsewhere, in one or more of various different places.)

Note, by the way, that in the drawings here, commits `A-B-C-D` are on *both branches*.  Commits `E-F` are only on `develop`.  But since we can move branch names, we could change this by moving `master` to point to `F`.  That would make all six commits be on both branches.  We do not have to change the *commits* to do this, which is necessary, since we can't. :-)

Graphs can get much more complicated.  Rather than showing a very complicated one (like the one you probably actually have), here's a simpler one that shows what happens when we commit a merge.  Here's the *before* picture:

```
          I--J   <-- release (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop
```

and the *after* one:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- release (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- develop
```

The new merge commit `M` is only on `release`.  It has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.  Commit `J` is only on release and it has one parent `I`.  Commit `L` is on *both branches* and it has one parent `K`.  Both `I` and `K` lead back to commit `H`, which is on both branches, and that leads back to `G`, which is on both, and so on.

#### This is where `git log` comes in

If you run `git log` without giving it some starting commit, Git looks at your `HEAD` to find your current commit.  Your current commit is the one your branch name points to.  You mention in a comment that you are on your `release` branch and that it points to a merge commit.  So your picture probably looks something like what we just drew.

The `git log` command will start from commit `M` and show it to you.  Then it adds *all* of `M`'s parents to the list of commits it needs to show.  It must now try to show you both `J` and `L` *at the same time*.  It can't, so it picks one of these two to show.  Then it adds the parent of whichever one it showed, to its list of things to show.

If it just showed `J`, `git log` now has two commits to show you at the same time, namely `L` and `I`.  It can't show both at the same time, so it picks one.  Then it adds that one's parent to its list, and so on.

The `git log` command will intermingle the commits from the two sides of the merge, by default.  In particular, it shows them one at a time based on the *time stamp*, so that you see the newer ones first.  If `J` is newer than `L` you'll see `J` before `L`, but if `L` is newer than `J` you'll see `L` first.  The same goes for `I` and `K` (vs both `L` and `J`).  But `git log` *does* respect the shape of the graph in that no matter what else it does, it won't show `H` until it's finished showing `I-J` and `K-L`.

Eventually, it will be able to show `H`, and when it does the list of other commits to show will be empty.  It will show `H`, add `H`'s parent `G` to the list to show (which now has just one entry), then show `G` and add `G`'s parent, and so on.

But `git log` *won't* show commits it cannot get to by starting at `M` and working backwards!

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- release (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- develop
              \
               N--O--P   <-- another-name
```

Suppose there's some *other* name remembering a hash ID `P`.  This might not be a *branch* name: maybe it's a name like `origin/develop` or `origin/master`, that your Git uses to remember branch names your Git saw in some other Git.

Running `git log` *won't* show commit `P`.  Having not shown `P` it won't move back to `O` either.  Git literally cannot go from `L` to `N`.  It can only go from `N` to `L`, *backwards*.  You need to pick a starting commit hash that start at or beyond the commit you care about, to see the commit you care about.

Note that commits `N-O-P` here are not "on" `release`.  We use the word "on" to mean "commits reachable from the tip".  The tip of `release` is commit `M` and commit `N` cannot be reached by going backwards from `M`.

Note that commit `M` cannot be reached by going backwards from `N` either!  Two commits can have a common ancestor without themselves having a parent/child or grandparent/grandchild relationship.  The fact that they have a common ancestor may only make them siblings or cousins.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably not up to date or on the wrong branch.
try directly the sha1

```
git log 8d69
```

after a `git fetch --all`

Comment: Interesting, when I use this command git log 8d6995e4 I see the log starting from  8d6995e4n and later.  However, git log | grep 8d6995e4 . gives nothing.  So, what 8d6995e4 indicates?

Comment: this indicates that git knows about this sha1 but that you are probably not on the right branch. Try checking out the right branch (from the name you have on gitlab) (`git checkout 'branch_name'`)

Comment: I can see the description: Merge branch 'release' into 'master'. I am on the release branch

Comment: if you see merge release in master, you should probably be on master. Maybe you should use some visual tool like gitk or tig to help you figure out all this